# Embed yyparse(), generated by Flex and Bison, on CLI program written in C language

Tags: c, command-line-interface, bison

I'm working on a improved version of mfcalc example given in the bison manual and you can find the code [here](https://github.com/jcatumba/mfcalc).

I'm stuck trying to use yyparse() from main.c file, actually the code works fine with

```
int main (int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    init_table ();
    return yyparse ();
}
```

but I want to add a prompt to that, so I wrote

```
int main (int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char command[101];
    FILE *fp;
    init_table ();

    while (1) {
        printf ("[mfcalc]: "); /*prompt*/
        memset (command, 0x00, sizeof(command));
        fgets (command, 100, stdin);
        fp = fopen("command.txt", "w+");
        fprintf(fp, "%s", command);
        yyin = fp;
        yyparse ();
        fscanf (yyout, "%s", output);
        printf ("%s\n", output);
        fclose (fp);
    }
}
```

this is, redefine yyin from `stdin` to a regular file, put a prompt message, execute the parser on yyin, read the output from yyout and print to screen. But this doesn't work correctly, I get just a blank line. When I prove the program I get:

```
[mfcalc]: 3 + 4

[mfcalc]:
```

Also, the error codes are not shown. Any ideas to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing `fscanf()` on `yyout`?  That's an output file, isn't it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes its a mistake, I change it on last commit at [repo](https://github.com/jcatumba/mfcalc). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't compiled it, but after reading your code I think the problem may be the file. The file pointer is at the end of the file after writing, and therefore there is no input for yyparse. 
You could use fseek and fsetpos to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just rewrite mfcalc's scanner to take characters from the string instead of a file?

Comment: The `yyparse()` function takes `yyin` as its entry value and `yyin` is always a FILE, isn't it?

Comment: `yyparse()` calls `yylex()`, that one is the function reading input.

Comment: Yes, `yylex()` by default reads from a file. But either (a) you are changing the `mfcalc` from `bison(1)`'s manual, there `yylex()` is a hand-written function, easy to change to get data from a string instead of reading from a file, or (b) you have some `yylex()` written by `flex(1)`, and there are mechanisms to change its input to take a string.

Comment: you don't even need to read from a string. Using gnu-flex, you can just redefine YY_INPUT to write the prompt. With most other flex's, you can redefine the function input(). For gnu-flex, see the description of YY_INPUT here: http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Generated-Scanner.html#Generated-Scanner

Comment: @rici, I suspect OP is using a handwritten parser (the one in `mfcalc` in the `bison` manual). And flex is _not_ part of GNU, it is a completely separate development under the BSD license.

Comment: @vonbrand: you may well be right about the lexer, although the question is tagged gnu-flex and the handwritten lexer in the bison manual doesn't have any `yyin`. I know that flex is not really GNU, although it generally finds its way into gnu distros. It's really unfortunate that Macromedia "repurposed" the name for a completely different product which should now be called "Apache flex" but which I think is still commonly known as "Adobe flex".

Comment: @rici, fixed the tag. And yes, asigning to yyin when it isn't used could cause the "no input" OP is seeing...